# How to get selected option value of dropdown in angularjs and change the div id dynamically onchange of dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using angularjs. I have a select box and divs coming from ng repeat.Here on change of select box I need to change the div id dynamically.For ex. if my option selected value is city then div id will be {{y.city}} again if my option selected value is state then div id will be {{y.state}}.Just to show, I put id="{{y.state}}" inside div. Can anyone please help me,Here is the code below.

### HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<select class="change" ng-model="x" ng-change="update()">
<option vlaue="city">Cities</option>
<option vlaue="state">States</option>
<option vlaue="country">Countries</option>
</select>
<div ng-repeat="y in details" id="{{y.state}}">
{{y.state}}
</div>
</div>
```

### Script

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.details = [{"city":"city1","id":"1","state":"state1","country":"country1"},{"city":"city2","id":"2","state":"state2","country":"country2"},{"city":"city3","id":"3","state":"state3","country":"country3"}];
  console.log($scope.details[0].city);
  $scope.update = function() { 
   if($scope.x == 'city'){
   alert('this is city');
   }
   if($scope.x == 'state'){
   alert('this is state');
   }
   if($scope.x == 'country'){
   alert('this is city');
   }

}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix typo `vlaue` -> `value`

Your code will be:

```
<div ng-repeat="y in details" id="{{ y[x] }}">
    {{y[x]}}
</div>
```

http://embed.plnkr.co/7W830qHem09Xr8Iw2siG

Comment: could you update the question with the new not working solution?

Comment: Here first I need to get the value of selected option onchange of dropdown,then   if my  selected value is city then automatically an  id will be {{y.city}} added to the div ,again   if my  selected value is state then automatically an  id will be {{y.state}} added to the div